# Grid alignment syntax

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

This is a simple question, but I just cannot understand the explanation given in the [Grid documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) for how to set different alignments for different parts of a grid. I have a grid with two rows with four columns each, and I would like the top row to be bottom aligned and the bottom row to be top aligned. Or, in general, I want to specify one alignment per row (again, for a two row grid). How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mat = {{Column[{12, 34}], 123, 1234, 5}, {Column[{1, 2}], 3, 4, 5}};
```

The default is center aligned rows and columns

```
mat // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

For top row to be bottom aligned and the bottom row to be top aligned

```
mat // Grid[#, Frame -> All,
   Alignment -> {Automatic, {Bottom, Top}}] &
```

[image]

You can specify any desired `Alignment`

```
mat // Grid[#, Frame -> All,
   Alignment -> {{Center, Left, Right, Center}, {Bottom, Top}}] &
```

[image]